# using Mousedown and setTimeout function to trigger a function over and over

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mousedown

I want to use call function repeatedly while mousedown event using setTimeout, it's not working at all. anyone have any idea?

```
    $("#image_360").mousedown( function() {
        mouseStillDown=true;
        $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function () {

            getDirection;
        }, 2000));
    },
    function()
    {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
        alert('mouse left');

    });

    function getDirection(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
            //do stuff with condition e.pageX
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` methods for repeatedly calling and clearing the timer instead of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)

Update your code like this

```
    $("#image_360").mousedown( function() {
        mouseStillDown=true;
        $(this).data('timeout', window.setInterval(function () {

            getDirection;
        }, 2000));
    },
    function()
    {
        clearInterval($(this).data('timeout'));
        alert('mouse left');

    });
```

then `getDirection` will be called every 2 second.